# What is the difference between objects and classes in Python

Tags: python, class, object

I am a self-taught python user (kind of.). I read much to deepen my knowledge about python. Today

I encountered a text saying:

> ... classes and objects ....

So I was wondering what is the difference between objects and classes in python. I taught all classes are objects, but in that case, author wouldn't have used phrase "classes and objects". I'm confused...

Comment: Wasn't the wikipedia page on OO programming helpful for this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming seems clear.  What was confusing about the wikipedia page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are two closely related terms in object oriented programming. The standard meaning is that an *object* is an instance of a *class*.

Answer (score 7):

An object is an instantiation of a class.

Think of a class like the blueprint of a car.

Ford make cars (objects) based on the rules and information enclosed in the blueprint.

Comment: and class is instantiation of what?

Comment: @Aleksey a class is an instantiation of a metaclass of course. Before you ask, a metaclass is also an instantiation of a metaclass and in Python terms the default metaclass 'type' is an instance of itself. i.e. `type(type) is type`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, classes (and functions, and modules, and basically everything) in Python are objects, too. The difference lies in their types:

```
class Foo(object): pass
print type(Foo)
print type(Foo())
```

To see they're both objects, you can check that they both have attributes:

```
print dir(Foo)
print dir(Foo())
```

Answer (score 3):

A class describes what that object will be, but it isn't the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

A class is an idea.  An object is the fruition of that idea.