# What is an Object and a Class in python?

Tags: conceptual

I came across the following line:

> Every **list object** that you create in Python is actually an instance of **List class**.

What does Class and Object actually mean?

[Another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483947/what-is-the-difference-between-objects-and-classes-in-python)

I saw the above post but in that they explain the difference between object and class. But what exactly is a class if Object is an instance of class.

Edit:

What is an instance?

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica In the above post, i just find the difference between them. Like in an answer the following was said: 'An Object is an instance of class' But what exactly is a class and an object?

Comment: Moreover, what is an instance?

Answer (score 2):

Think of classes as blueprints for objects. So for example, you will only have one car model blueprint, and that is your class. Every single model that is produced is an instance. Hope it helps.

Comment: What does the line that I mentioned mean then?

Comment: Also, what is an instance?